# Error "connect ECONNREFUSED" when sending a request using Axios

Tags: node.js, axios

I am getting this error while sending requests to use Axios in Nodejs get request. I am calling the 3rd party API.

```
{
  "message": "connect ECONNREFUSED 198.54.117.197:443",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 198.54.117.197:443\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)",
  "config": {
    "url": "https://swapi.co/api/starships/9",
    "method": "get",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "User-Agent": "axios/0.21.0"
    },
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1
  },
  "code": "ECONNREFUSED"
}
```

> My code
> https://github.com/bilalyaqoob/caching-with-node-js-redis

Can anybody help me?

Comment: It seems like to remote server isn't accepting your request. Please check if you have proper Auth setup and that the API is working.

Comment: I am using this https://swapi.dev/

Answer (score 0):

You are using an outdated endpoint. On the website it states that you need to use https://swapi.dev/api/starships/9/ instead of ttps://swapi.co/api/starships/9 .
They moved from a .co to a .dev domain.